# How to implement validation to moveiploadfile(size and type) in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'], $name )) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

I need to implement restriction for uploading files in terms of size and type.
Users should not be able to upload files that size is larger than 2 megabyte and should upload only PDF documents. If user do not perform these validation rules, it should show error message. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use Yii validation rules.

1. Add [rule in the model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules).
2. Set [maxSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#maxSize-detail) and [types](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#types-detail) settings for the rule.
3. [Handle the file upload](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/) in a controller.

Comment: I cannot add any validation to this code, because I am taking files through widget

Comment: Is it your custom widget?

Comment: it is not mine, but I took it from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Try this before upload code :

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
//For size
if($_FILES["Upload"]["size"]>20000000) //2 mb
    {
    echo "File size should be less than 2MB";   
    }
// for extention
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
if($ext=='pdf' )
{
echo "write the code to upload file";
}
else
{
echo "Only jpg or gif file is allowed";
}
```

Hope it helps !!!